# I can't understand function definiton (argument with '=')

Tags: python, function

I found this function in a Python quiz:

```
def calculate (num1, num2=4):
    res = num1 * num2
    print(res)

calculate(5, 6)
```

What does `num2=4` mean?

It multiplies 5 and 6 which is understandable... But I don't understand why the answer is not changed rather than being 30?

I thought `num2=4` has to do something with it which may change the answer something else than 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the default value 
look at this example:

```py
def calculate (num1, num2=4): 
    res = num1 * num2
    print(res)

calculate(5)
```

#### output

```
20
```

In this example because you dont have second parameter it will consider the default value

Comment: yepppp...finally got it...Thanks alot man

Comment: you're welcome, if my answer helped you with your question, I would appreciate it if you choose it as the best answer as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If no value for num2 is given, it will default to multiply num1 by 4

Answer (score 0):

It's the default value for your fun if no second parameter is passed.

So if you call `calculate(5)` the result would be 20
If you call `calculate(5,2)` the result would be 10